# How To Count Case Sensitive Independent Words In File

Tags: python, python-3.x

How do I count a word in a file using a boolean if the word is exactly the same as the user input?

So, if `case sensitive == True` it will only count it if the case matches. The word also cannnot be a part of another word.

For example: if `input = Apple` the code will count only words `Apple` or `Apple` or `+Apple-`. But it will not count  words `apple` or `applepie` or `apples`.

I made a template to show what I mean:

```
  # open the file
  f = open("months.txt")

  # ask for word to search
  word = input("What word do you want to search (Note: Case Sensitive): ")

  # read each line in the file
  for month in f.readlines():

  # <Code to only count case sensitive, independent words, in file "months.exe". (Boolean)>
  # <Code to print number of how many times the word appears>

  f.close()
```

Comment: If I didn't misunderstand, then you can just use the `str.count(substring)` method to find the amount of occurences of `substring` in `str`-- which is case-sensitive IIRC

Comment: I didn't understand anything here, unfortunately. Finding a substring in a string "case-insensitively" is easy, but deciding whether a chunk of characters surrounded by spaces is a word may be a bit tricky.

Comment: Sorry for my bad explanation, I didn't fully understand what my professor wanted as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`re.findall()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#re.findall) and format the user input into the pattern:

```
import re

word = ...
with open("months.txt") as f:
    count = sum(len(re.findall(r'\b{}\b'.format(word), line)) for line in f)
```

**`\b`** marks a word boundary in the regular expression:

```
>>> word = 'Apple'
>>> len(re.findall(r'\b{}\b'.format(word),  "Apple. or Apple? or +Apple- Applepie"))
3
```

Comment: It should match a user input. So, you should wrap it up into a method, where you pass a word to be counted.

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for.